# extjs decimal places renderer

Tags: extjs

In extjs, for the record object, is there a awy to get a particular data index. What I need is this:
I have a renderer function that formats decimals. If the dataIndex of the record is a 'dollaramount', i format one way. If something else, I format another way.
So the function is:

```
decimalsRenderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store){
if (record.data.index =='amount')
//  format using 2 decimals
else
//format using 3 decimals
```

},

But record.data.index is not allowed. How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confusing column and record.
Record does not have dataIndex but Column has one.
dataIndex for the column tells the grid "*for this column, we want to look at this particular field from the store*"

That said, here is how you can obtain the dataIndex i.e. the field name (from store's point of view) in your column renderer -

```
//columnIndex is availble in renderer fn
var fieldName = grid.getColumnModel().getDataIndex(columnIndex); 
//Do your thing. check if fieldName is amount
```

Reference - [ColumnModel](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.grid.ColumnModel)